# Selector for Imageview in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, focus, pressed

I have a problem with ImageView in my ListView.
I want to change its drawable according the specified selector.

My ListView item is a simple LinearLayout, containing a TextView and an ImageView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightMenuItemName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        style="@style/right_menu_item_name"
        />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/rightMenuItemIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/selector_menu_item"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The selector_menu_item drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/right_menu_s" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/right_menu_s" />
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/right_menu_s" />

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/right_menu" />

 </selector>
```

The ListView itself has his own selector for background coloring   android:listSelector="...". The TextView has also a color-selector for the foreground color. This both selectors works like expected, only the image of the ImageView will not change.

My Adapter:

```
public class RightMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    …

    @Override
    public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = newView(type, parent);
        }
        bindView(position, type, convertView);
        return convertView;
    }



    @Override
    public View newView(int type, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_screens_right_menu, parent,
                false);
        v.setTag(new ViewHolder(v));

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(int position, int type, View view) {
        ScreenNavigationData item = items.get(position);

        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        vh.name.setText(item.getMenuTitle());

    }


}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, I found the solution:

I have to remove the  android:clickable="true" attribute from the ImageView. Now everything works ...

Thank you anyway for your help!

Comment: Hey can you have a look at this and help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068765/listview-image-selector-android?

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener won't fire :(

Answer (score 3):

change android:src="@
drawable/selector_menu_
item"/> to android:background="@
drawable/selector_menu_
item"/>

Comment: unfortunately it has no effect

Comment: and what if you change ImageView to View and set fixed layout_width and latout_height to say 50dp?

Comment: did not change the behaviour

Comment: hmm, i did same thing couple of times and it worked with no peoblems... are you sure that drawable/right_menu and drawable/right_menu_s differ?

Comment: I found the problem: android:clickable="true" was the problem. Btw. I have specified the selector as android:src and not as android:background

Answer (score 1):

If you are overriding `getView()` of your `list adapter` surely this will work. Kindly note down, from your xml you are using same image only for all state.

Comment: Of course I have implemented an own adapter, but the image view does not change his image

Comment: Can you post your `getView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is only partial fix for the problem.
If you need to have click event added to `ImageView`, then even if you set it in XML, it won't work.

What you need to do is set the `android:duplicateParentState="true"` parameter in `ImageView` XML, so it get working and you still can have the ImageView clickable.

My ImageView XML looks like so:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFavIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_history_fav" 
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />
```

and selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_hist_add_fav_highlighted"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_hist_add_fav_normal"/>
</selector>
```

I spent few hours of checking different paths, hope it helps someone...